# error.network.private_messaging_blocked for replies to facebook private message

Tags: socialpost, social-customer-service

I can find no mention of the error we are occasionally seeing. We've had Social Customer Service setup for years and in a few different orgs without issue.

The error message we are getting is "error.network.private_messaging_blocked". When I first saw it I assumed this particular FB user has revoked permission for apps to send them private messages, but we've seen it for multiple users now in the space of a few days. It's only happening on one of our social accounts so far.

I've raised a case with Salesforce to get some clarity on the issue and will update here when I get a response.

Anyone else having the same issue, or has seen it before?

Answer (score 0):

Response from Salesforce:

Facebook is introducing a change on June 30th that will impact inbox messages within Social Customer Service and Social Studio. To prevent any downtime you will be required to reauthorize all your Facebook social accounts in Social Studio prior to June 15th 2020.

You can see the changes in their developer documentation located here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/message
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/conversation

Please use the steps listed in the article to reauthorize the Facebook pages in Social Studio

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000353040&type=1&mode=1

Once complete, go the Salesforce and refresh the social account list using the steps listed below

1. Setup
2. Quick find Social Customer Service
3. Social Accounts
4. Click on the curved arrow on the top right hand side to refresh the list.